# How Do We Debug SkPathGlue Crashes?

Tags: android

I am getting a bunch of crashes in `SkPathGlue`, both its `approximate()` and `isRectContour()` functions. Here's a sample native dump from one of the `approximate()` crashes, which is the more common of the two crashes:

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> co.snicklefritz.android <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 0000000000347148  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::SkPathGlue::approximate(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, long, float)+580)
  #00  pc 0000000000240fb0  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (art_jni_trampoline+160)
  #00  pc 000000000040ed9c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.graphics.Path.approximate+60)
  #00  pc 000000000043d1c0  /data/app/~~ddTWSA2JWd81lFOpINkMdg==/co.snicklefritz.android-bvDqwzGOE-MRWgoGj5rMrA==/oat/arm64/base.odex (fsimpl.aE.a+96)
  #00  pc 0000000000a9178c  /data/app/~~ddTWSA2JWd81lFOpINkMdg==/co.snicklefritz.android-bvDqwzGOE-MRWgoGj5rMrA==/oat/arm64/base.odex (fsimpl.aG.a+524)
  #00  pc 0000000000ac5c5c  /data/app/~~ddTWSA2JWd81lFOpINkMdg==/co.snicklefritz.android-bvDqwzGOE-MRWgoGj5rMrA==/oat/arm64/base.odex (fsimpl.O.a+444)
  #00  pc 0000000000ac6f5c  /data/app/~~ddTWSA2JWd81lFOpINkMdg==/co.snicklefritz.android-bvDqwzGOE-MRWgoGj5rMrA==/oat/arm64/base.odex (fsimpl.O.a+2332)
  #00  pc 0000000000ac63d8  /data/app/~~ddTWSA2JWd81lFOpINkMdg==/co.snicklefritz.android-bvDqwzGOE-MRWgoGj5rMrA==/oat/arm64/base.odex (fsimpl.O.a+232)
  #00  pc 0000000000ab324c  /data/app/~~ddTWSA2JWd81lFOpINkMdg==/co.snicklefritz.android-bvDqwzGOE-MRWgoGj5rMrA==/oat/arm64/base.odex (fsimpl.dx.java_sync_scan_ui+284)
  #00  pc 0000000000134564  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548)
  #00  pc 0000000000198e94  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+204)
  #00  pc 0000000000532198  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+104)
  #00  pc 0000000000533398  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues<art::ArtMethod*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, art::ArtMethod*, jvalue const*)+440)
  #00  pc 0000000000393ef4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI<false>::CallIntMethodA(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, jvalue const*)+652)
  #00  pc 00000000000425f8  /data/app/~~ddTWSA2JWd81lFOpINkMdg==/co.snicklefritz.android-bvDqwzGOE-MRWgoGj5rMrA==/base.apk!libfs-native.so (offset 0x2490000)
  #00  pc 000000000001611c  /data/app/~~ddTWSA2JWd81lFOpINkMdg==/co.snicklefritz.android-bvDqwzGOE-MRWgoGj5rMrA==/base.apk!libfs-native.so (offset 0x2490000)
  #00  pc 0000000000020b24  /data/app/~~ddTWSA2JWd81lFOpINkMdg==/co.snicklefritz.android-bvDqwzGOE-MRWgoGj5rMrA==/base.apk!libfs-native.so (offset 0x2490000)
  #00  pc 000000000001e8f4  /data/app/~~ddTWSA2JWd81lFOpINkMdg==/co.snicklefritz.android-bvDqwzGOE-MRWgoGj5rMrA==/base.apk!libfs-native.so (offset 0x2490000)
  #00  pc 00000000000841e0  /data/app/~~ddTWSA2JWd81lFOpINkMdg==/co.snicklefritz.android-bvDqwzGOE-MRWgoGj5rMrA==/base.apk!libfs-native.so (offset 0x2490000)
  #00  pc 0000000000083a74  /data/app/~~ddTWSA2JWd81lFOpINkMdg==/co.snicklefritz.android-bvDqwzGOE-MRWgoGj5rMrA==/base.apk!libfs-native.so (offset 0x2490000)
  #00  pc 00000000000368d8  /data/app/~~ddTWSA2JWd81lFOpINkMdg==/co.snicklefritz.android-bvDqwzGOE-MRWgoGj5rMrA==/base.apk!libfs-native.so (offset 0x2490000)
  #00  pc 000000000003985c  /data/app/~~ddTWSA2JWd81lFOpINkMdg==/co.snicklefritz.android-bvDqwzGOE-MRWgoGj5rMrA==/base.apk!libfs-native.so (offset 0x2490000)
  #00  pc 00000000000aaad4  /data/app/~~ddTWSA2JWd81lFOpINkMdg==/co.snicklefritz.android-bvDqwzGOE-MRWgoGj5rMrA==/base.apk!libfs-native.so (offset 0x2490000)
  #00  pc 00000000000b6234  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+64)
  #00  pc 0000000000050e64  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64)
```

These in turn seem to map to `approximate()` and `isRect()` functions on `Path`. However, my app code is not using either of those directly.

These are not crashing "in the lab". The `approximate()` one seems exclusive to Android 11 Samsung devices, and the `isRect()` one may be exclusive to Android 7.x.

How can we tell where in the app (our code or third-party libraries) these crashes are coming from?

Comment: Is that all from the stack trace?

Comment: @Quicklearner: That came from the Play Console, and that's all that was in the console stack trace listing.

Comment: If possible can you try with debug mode with the respective device?

Comment: @Quicklearner: Since I cannot reproduce the crash, I do not know how that would help. The stack traces are showing up in Play Console, not during development.